# Getting a Cannot read property 'controls' of undefined error

Tags: angular

I am getting this error "Cannot read property 'controls' of undefined"  in my Form Builder.

My code is as follows

I initialize initForm in the constructor

```
this.initForm();
```

My initForm method

```
  private initForm() {
    this._userService.getCurrentUserProfileData(this._getProfileToUpdate())
      .subscribe((user) => {
        this.userFormGroup = new FormGroup({
          firstName: new FormControl(user.firstName, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-Z]*$')]),
          lastName: new FormControl(user.lastName, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-Z]*$')]),
          email: new FormControl(user.email, [Validators.required, Validators.email]),
          mobile: new FormControl(user.mobile, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[0-9]*$')]),
          workNumber: new FormControl(user.workNumber, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[0-9]*$')]),
          role: new FormControl(user.roleId, Validators.required)
        });
      }, (error) => {
        this._errorService.openErrorPopup('Failed to get profile data.');
      }
    );
  }
```

My model

```
  private _getProfileToUpdate() {
    return {
      firstName: this.userFormGroup.controls.firstName.value,
      lastName: this.userFormGroup.controls.lastName.value,
      email: this.userFormGroup.controls.email.value,
      mobile: this.userFormGroup.controls.mobile.value,
      workNumber: this.userFormGroup.controls.workNumber.value,
      roleId: this.userFormGroup.controls.role.value,
    };
  }
```

I am not sure why this is happening. I initially though it was that the method was not being initialized before the html was being displayed.

Comment: Why are you calling ` _getProfileToUpdate()` before you have initialized the formGroup? Your formGroup is not initialized under this method, so the error

Comment: yes thank you, you are spot on

Comment: As @xyz said you should init form first with empty values then update formControls value with patchValue or setValue after api response.

Comment: I usually write my form like `<form *ngIf="userFormGroup " [formGroup]="userFormGroup ">..</form>` to avoid initial errors